# Como rodar um Word Macro via Python?

Tags: python, macro, microsoft-word

```
import os
import comtypes.client

path=r"path to the .docm file where I saved the vba macro"

word=comtypes.client.CreateObject("Word.Application")
word.Documents.Open(path,ReadOnly=1)
word.Run("Project.Modulo1.ConvertDoc")
word.Documents(1).Close(SaveChanges=0)
word.Application.Quit()
wd=0
```

Tentei isso, mas obtive o seguinte erro:

> `"NULL COM Pointer Acess"`

Comment: Olhando o código me parece correto. Eu sugiro uma conferida no endereço do arquivo da macro, nome da macro dentro do arquivo e localização interna da macro dentro do arquivo

Comment: Estou recebendo: " NULL COM Pointer Acess" , conhece algum tutorial para run word macro com python? Achei bastante informação para Excel Macro, mas não estou conseguindo adaptar para word.

Comment: Qual linha aponta este erro?